# Replace files with updated version using batch

Tags: batch-file

i am trying to replace multiple files with updated versions using batch, what i have currently doesn't want to work. the only diference between the new file and old is the date, i was then going to loop it as the file to be replaced directory changes slightly to c:\test3\hazards-file2-data.csv.

```
CLS
set /p vtdate= Enter existing valid till date:
set /p yesno= Confirm this is the correct valid till date?[y/n/c to cancel]:

if "%yesno%"=="n" goto VTD
if "%yesno%"=="y" goto VFD 
if "%yesno%"=="c" goto Home
if not "%yesno%"=="y"or"n"or"c" goto IED
pause
goto VTD

:VFD
set /p vfdate= Enter valid from date:
Set /p yesno= Confirm this is the correct valid from date?[y/n/c to       cancel]:

if "%yesno%"=="n" goto VFD
if "%yesno%"=="y" goto Copy 
if "%yesno%"=="c" goto Home
if not "%yesno%"=="y"or"n"or"c" goto VFD
pause
goto VFD

:Copy
cd c:\>replace c:\Test2\"%vfdate%"-hazards-File1-data.csv:\Test1\"%vtdate%"-hazards-File1-data.csv
```

Comment: it's ok i just had to simplify my thinking, i used del then copy rather than a replace function. 'del /f /q/ c:\test2\ "%vtdate%"-hazards-file1-data.csv' followed by 'copy c:\test1 "%vfd%"-hazrads-file1-data.csv c:\test 2'

Comment: Take a look at `xcopy /?` or `robocopy /?`...

Comment: thanks will look at it.